# running python script inside makefile is not working

Tags: python, bash, makefile

I want to run a python file **example.py** in a makefile:

```
python ../example.py; \
```

exmaple.py:

```
import os

f = open("test2.txt", "w")
f.write(os.getcwd())
f.close()
```

but the above command does not work and no **test2.txt** file is created.

If I run the same code inline with the -c flag, it works and **test1.txt** is created and the cwd is getting written to it.

```
python -c 'import os; f = open("test1.txt", "w"); f.write(os.getcwd()); f.close();' \
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

**EDIT**
The surrounding lines in the Makefile:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/$(FW_BASE).elf: $(FW_OBJS) $(TARGET_LIB_NAMES) $(rom_syms) fw.ld MemoryMap.ld $(OBJ_DIR)/overlay.ld
    @echo "Creating $@ for $(FW_BASE)"
    $(eval globalVar= $(shell $(NM) -S --radix dec $(FW_OBJS) $(TARGET_LIB_NAMES) | grep ' D \| B ' | tr -d '\r' | \
    awk  '{ FS=" "; k=0; split($$0, val); printf "--defsym __sizeI_%s=%d ", val[4], val[2]; k+=val[2]}';) --defsym INTLV=$(interleave))
    @$(eval sem := $@.sem)
    $(VERB)if $(PYBUILD)'ovl_layout(job=1, dn_obj="$(OBJ_DIR)", fn_lscript="$(FW_LD)")' && \
              $(LINK) $(FW_OBJS) -R $(rom_syms) $(TARGET_LIB_ARGS) --defsym __boot0_size=$(IRAM_SIZE) --defsym __boot1_size=$(OVERLAY_SIZE_BYTES) --defsym __cfe_size=$(CFE_SIZE) --defsym __cfe_storage_size=$(CFE_STORAGE_SIZE) -o $@ -T MemoryMap.ld -T $(FW_LD) -Map $(basename $@).map -r $(overlay_real) && \
              $(PYBUILD)'ovl_layout(job=2, dn_obj="$(OBJ_DIR)", fn_lscript="$(FW_LD)", fn_map="$(basename $@).map")' && \
              $(LINK) $(FW_OBJS) -R $(rom_syms) $(TARGET_LIB_ARGS) --defsym __boot0_size=$(IRAM_SIZE) --defsym __boot1_size=$(OVERLAY_SIZE_BYTES) --defsym __cfe_size=$(CFE_SIZE) --defsym __cfe_storage_size=$(CFE_STORAGE_SIZE) -o $@ -T MemoryMap.ld -T $(FW_LD) -Map $(basename $@).map -r $(overlay_real) $(globalVar) && \
              $(enum-sems) "$@" "$(sem)" && \
              $(LINK) $(FW_OBJS) -R $(rom_syms) $(TARGET_LIB_ARGS) --defsym __boot0_size=$(IRAM_SIZE) --defsym __boot1_size=$(OVERLAY_SIZE_BYTES) --defsym __cfe_size=$(CFE_SIZE) --defsym __cfe_storage_size=$(CFE_STORAGE_SIZE) $(extra_syms) @$(sem) -o $@ -T MemoryMap.ld -T $(FW_LD) -Map $(basename $@).map $(overlay_real) $(globalVar) \
              $(LDFLAGS); then $(SZ) $@; \
                               # python -c 'import os; f = open("test.txt", "w"); f.write(os.getcwd()); f.close();' \
                               python ../example.py; \
                               # $(PYBUILD) 'get_branch_addresses(elf_file="$(@)")'; \
                               $(NM) $(rom_syms) --format=possix | awk '{print $$1;}' > $(OBJ_DIR)/rom-symbols.txt; else \
                               $(VERB)$(dump-mem) $(basename $@).map; fi || ( $(VERB)$(dump-mem) $(basename $@).map; false; )
```

Comment: Please show a more complete example.  Are you sure the `python ../example.py;` command is being run in the directory in which you expect it to be run?

Comment: What is the relevant piece in the makefile, maybe include that too, and where is it run from?

Comment: @AndrewHolmgren  I can add the surrounding lines in the makefile. It's pretty huge so I thought maybe that's more confusing than helping

Answer (score 0):

A possible problem is that your python script is not in the directory you expect. Another possible issue could be your Makefile. I re-created your described setup and was able to create the file. On a Ubuntu system all in the same directory;

```
# Makefile
all:
    python3 example.py
```

```py
# example.py
import os

f = open("test2.txt", "w")
f.write(os.getcwd())
f.close()
```

After running;

```sh
make
```

the test2.txt file is generated and contains the cwd

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your makefile...

Comment: Sure, no problem

Comment: I'm on windows 10 using cygwin. Maybe that's a problem?

Comment: I would double check your `/`. In Windows, they are reversed. I believe you can use ```\``` or ```//```. ex ```..\example.py```